# Extending existing TypeScript types

Tags: typescript

I use an existing class from a npm module declared like this:

```js
export class ServerRequest {
   url!: string;
   method!: string;
   headers!: Headers;
...
```

I want to be able to append my own parameter (let's say 'origin'), so I can call the 'ServerRequest' class like so:

```js
let serverRequest = new ServerRequest()
serverRequest.origin
```

But TypeScript raises an error:

> Property 'origin' does not exist on the type 'ServerRequest' ts(2339)

How can I append my own types without deleting or using a new/another type? I can, of course, silence the error with //@ts-ignore, but I want to be able to use static types in my code.

Comment: You can subclass `ServerRequest` like so: `class MyClass extends ServerRequest {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to sublass `ServerRequest` you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) by declaring an `interface` with the same name of the `class` and add custom properties:

```
export class ServerRequest {
   url!: string;
   method!: string;
   headers!: Headers;
   //...
}

export interface ServerRequest{
    origin: string;
}

let serverRequest = new ServerRequest();
serverRequest.origin = "my-origin";
```

Comment: You might want to include the link to the documentation for [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), which is what you're doing here.